# How to call ajax inside ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, coldfusion

Is it possible to make an ajax request inside another ajax request? because I need some data from first ajax request to make the next ajax request. Also, I am trying to do a post inside the success of a get.

When I am trying to execute the code, I am not able to get inside 'success' in the inner Ajax call. Can you please see if there are any discrepancies in the code below.

I am pointing to coldfusion cfc and functions in the url which are working fine in other parts of my code.

```
showpopup = function(b)
{             
     console.log(b);
     $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "somepathtocfc?method=somefunc&id="+b,
     async: true,
     success: function(r){
        const obj =  JSON.parse(r);
        if( obj.returnVal== true){
           const obj =  JSON.parse(r); 
           var str = 'IMG_764.jpg';
           var counter = 1 ;
           var dept= document.getElementById('dptdsc').value; 
           $.ajax({                                                                                       
              url: 'getdata.cfm',                                                                           
              data: 
              {                                                                                                      
              fileName: $.trim(str),                                                                                        
              position : counter,                                                                                           
              department : document.getElementById('dptdsc').value,                                                   
              listId : id,                                                                                  
              timestamp:(new Date()).getTime().toString(),                                                  
              },                                                                                           
              type: 'post',                                                                                
              success: function(newFile){                                                                                
              console.log('success');                                                                       
              }
            });
           alert ('files imported');
         } 
         else{
              alert ('sorry, please try again!!');
         }
    }
}); }
```

Comment: Put error callbacks on your requests to see if and why they fail.

Comment: I removed showpopup function and passed parameter b manually, surprisingly it was working fine. I was calling showpopup function on click of a button. Since I wanted this to be done only on click of a button.

Comment: For clarity, I'd probably separate the calls into 2 functions. Fire the 1st call and have its `success` method call the 2nd ajax function.  But it does raise the question of why 2 separate calls are needed...